# elasticsearch multi_match "A and B" results not equal to "B and A"

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got products index with lots of fields, particulary every one of them analyzed with morphology and synonym filter.

Simplified to just 2 fields index is here:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e287d328a72df07bc491312820ffdef

1st query:

```
GET /products/nms/_search
{
   "size": 40,
   "_source": {
      "include": [
         "_id"
      ]
   },
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "fields": [
            "subject.value^2",
            "colors"
         ],
         "minimum_should_match": "30%",
         "operator": "and",
         "query": "футболка белая",
         "type": "cross_fields"
      }
   }
}
```

Results:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 6615,
      "max_score": 9.118673,
```

And they are quite right.

But when I swap the words, 2nd query:

```
GET /products/nms/_search
{
   "size": 40,
   "_source": {
      "include": [
         "_id"
      ]
   },
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "fields": [
            "subject.value^2",
            "colors"
         ],
         "minimum_should_match": "30%",
         "operator": "and",
         "query": "белая футболка",
         "type": "cross_fields"
      }
   }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 145434,
      "max_score": 10.683464,
```

And there is nothing similar to first results, not a single match in top 100 hits.

Spent some time digging in it, but still can't get a solution.
I'm forced to use cross_fileds due to document structure (over 15 fields), and as far as I understand, in this case - Elastic count every hit of synonym on any field and there are ten of then for "белая" (white) and none for "футболка" (t-shirt).

For example, we have 4 docs

```
PUT products_color_test/nms/1
{
    "colors": "белая", //white
    "subject" : {
        "id" :1,
        "value": "футболка"} //t-shirt
}
PUT products_color_test/nms/2
{
    "colors": "черная", //black
    "subject" : {
        "id" :1,
        "value": "футболка"} //t-shirt
}
PUT products_color_test/nms/3
{
    "colors": "молочная", //synonym to white
    "subject" : {
        "id" :1,
        "value": "футболка"} //t-shirt
}
PUT products_color_test/nms/4
{
    "colors": "молочная", //synonym to white
    "subject" : {
        "id" :2,
        "value": "куртка"} //jacket
}
```

Let's test it.

```
GET /products_color_test/nms/_search
{
   "size": 40,
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "fields": [
            "subject.value^2",
            "colors"
         ],
         "minimum_should_match": "30%",
         "operator": "and",
         "query": "футболка белая",
         "type": "cross_fields"
      }
   }
}
```

Results are:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.58422226,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "products_color_test",
            "_type": "nms",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.58422226,
            "_source": {
               "colors": "молочная",
               "subject": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "value": "футболка"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "products_color_test",
            "_type": "nms",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.568724,
            "_source": {
               "colors": "белая",
               "subject": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "value": "футболка"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Almost corect, synonym hit gets higher score instead of exact hit.

But after swap:

```
GET /products_color_test/nms/_search
{
   "size": 40,
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "fields": [
            "subject.value^2",
            "colors"
         ],
         "minimum_should_match": "30%",
         "operator": "and",
         "query": "белая футболка",
         "type": "cross_fields"
      }
   }
}


   "hits": {
  "total": 3,
  "max_score": 0.58422226,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "products_color_test",
        "_type": "nms",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.58422226,
        "_source": {
           "colors": "молочная",
           "subject": {
              "id": 1,
              "value": "футболка"
           }
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "products_color_test",
        "_type": "nms",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.568724,
        "_source": {
           "colors": "белая",
           "subject": {
              "id": 1,
              "value": "футболка"
           }
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "products_color_test",
        "_type": "nms",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.46449086,
        "_source": {
           "colors": "молочная",
           "subject": {
              "id": 2,
              "value": "куртка" // jacket ----!!!!!----
           }
        }
     }
  ]
  }
}
```

Questions:

- Ok, synonyms counts as many as there are. But why scoring is different and depends on which position in sentence synonym candidate is taking?
- Is there a way to make ES to count just one hit of synonyms, preserving document structure and multi_match query with cross_fileds?

Thanks!

ps. sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding

```
"expand": false
```

to synonym filter solved the riddle. As I understand - that makes ES take only first synonym at index-time, but to use whole expand set at search-time.

Results are now similar for two swapped queries, and ES counts synonym hit only once

```
        "_explanation": {
           "value": 0.5622277,
           "description": "sum of:",
           "details": [
              {
                 "value": 0.5622277,
                 "description": "sum of:",
                 "details": [
                    {
                       "value": 0.37481847,
                       "description": "max of:",
                       "details": [
                          {
                             "value": 0.37481847,
                             "description": "weight(subject.value:футболка in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                             "details": [
                                {
                                   "value": 0.37481847,
                                   "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:",
                                   "details": [
                                      {
                                         "value": 0.37481847,
                                         "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                         "details": [
                                            {
                                               "value": 2,
                                               "description": "boost",
                                               "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=4)",
                                               "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                               "value": 0.18740924,
                                               "description": "queryNorm",
                                               "details": []
                                            }
                                         ]
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "value": 1,
                                         "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                                         "details": [
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                               "details": [
                                                  {
                                                     "value": 1,
                                                     "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                                     "details": []
                                                  }
                                               ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=4)",
                                               "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)",
                                               "details": []
                                            }
                                         ]
                                      }
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          }
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "value": 0.18740924,
                       "description": "max of:",
                       "details": [
                          {
                             "value": 0.18740924,
                             "description": "weight(colors:белый in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                             "details": [
                                {
                                   "value": 0.18740924,
                                   "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:",
                                   "details": [
                                      {
                                         "value": 0.18740924,
                                         "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                         "details": [
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=4)",
                                               "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                               "value": 0.18740924,
                                               "description": "queryNorm",
                                               "details": []
                                            }
                                         ]
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "value": 1,
                                         "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                                         "details": [
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                               "details": [
                                                  {
                                                     "value": 1,
                                                     "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                                     "details": []
                                                  }
                                               ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=4)",
                                               "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)",
                                               "details": []
                                            }
                                         ]
                                      }
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "value": 0,
                 "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                 "details": [
                    {
                       "value": 0,
                       "description": "# clause",
                       "details": []
                    },
                    {
                       "value": 0.18740924,
                       "description": "_type:nms, product of:",
                       "details": [
                          {
                             "value": 1,
                             "description": "boost",
                             "details": []
                          },
                          {
                             "value": 0.18740924,
                             "description": "queryNorm",
                             "details": []
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     },
```